# Editor window loses focus on shortcut view change

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Android studio, while having a .xml file (layout) open in editor window, there are two modes available: Design and Text. In Mac the short-cut for going back and forth in these views are said to be Control + Shift and Left/Right. However once you press one of these combination the editor window will lose the focus and in order to go back, you have to click on the editor window.
How can one resolve that without the extra click?

Comment: So have you found the answer? If yes please share

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil Nothing yet.

Comment: Same issue occurs, when changing tab through alt key in windows. Android Studio 3.3

Comment: Did u find a solution? I got the same thing, upgrading android studio does not help.